# Can SharePoint Workflow be triggered by date?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I know that SharePoint workflow can be triggered by ITEM CREATED, ITEM CHANGED, MANUALLY.

But, is it possible for workflow to be triggered on a specific date (probably on 5th May every year) without any help of manual job? (probably other solution than pause until date/time).

Because right now, I need to create a workflow that send email to all list contributors (so they get notified to update the list)

Answer (score 4):

To do this you will need to use an Information Management Policy

I found this tutorial which may help you. [How to configure a yearly reminder on a SharePoint document](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2012/12/17/how-to-configure-a-yearly-reminder-on-a-sharepoint-document#.V1p4tLsrK70)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is in your list but you could create a workflow that Loops.  (some sudo workflow)

> Set variable $date to may 5 2017
>
> > Loop statement
> >
> > > Pause till $date
> > >               Do your actions
> > >               add 365 days to $date
> > >               then it loops back

Not supper elegant but this might work.
Other option is to start workflow via powershell as a schedule task.